# Bash scripting regarding Wget with credentials

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, wget, postdata

I am trying to do a script to log on a certain site and get the page infos as I would be logged.
I've searched on stacks and it appears that I must do it with 3 wgets:
one to get the hidden token , one for the cookies and post datas and the last one to get what I want. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# get the login page to get the hidden field data
wget -a log.txt -O loginpage.html --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0" site/login
hiddendata=$(cat loginpage.html | grep __Req | cut -d'"' -f6,6 | head -n1 | sed s/\"//g)


echo "Logging with user $1 and pass $2"
wget --secure-protocol=auto --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data="LoginDataModel.LoginName=$1&LoginDataModel.Password=$2&__RequestVerificationToken=${hidden_data}" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0" site/login/login
```

where site/login is the login page and site/login/login is the post action and the post-data values are the

```
Logging with user x and pass y
--2015-02-07 12:29:07--  site/Login/Login
Resolving site (site)... 91.208.180.39
Connecting to site (site)|91.208.180.39|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: site/Login/Login [following]
--2015-02-07 12:29:18--  site/Login/Login
Resolving site (site)... 91.208.180.39
Connecting to site (site)|91.208.180.39|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-02-07 12:29:23 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

when I check , the site/login/login exists. what am I doing wrong? Thank you.
I haven't done yet the third wget to get what I want since I can't connect properly.

Comment: Did you try to `echo` the full wget command and run it manually?

Comment: yes , I tried, there's no difference. First I thought it's because I'm not using any ssl protocols, but that didn't solve the matter.after it connects to https://site/login/login it gets moved to http://site/login/login and get 404'd.site/login/login exists.

Comment: I suspect that it's an SSL issue, note that your first try is to HTTPS (port 443) and it's being redirected to port 80 (HTTP). Use a tool like wireshark to sniff the HTTP session when you login from your browser and look for the difference.

Comment: I would suggest using curl instead, the verbose mode shows you the headers very handy for debugging

Answer (score 0):

I still can't comment so I will post it as answer. I would recommend to use `curl` instead of `wget`.
An example how to do it with `curl`: [Appnexus Authentication Service](http://wiki.appnexus.com/display/sdk/Authentication+Service). By your description its exactly what you need.

---

http://wiki.appnexus.com/display/sdk/Authentication+Service